# Message sent to deallocated instance on device only

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory

I'm at a complete loss with a memory bug. This issue only `happens` on the `device` and not the `simulator`. It also only happens when the app is loaded for the first time on the device. If I close the app and relaunch it the issue does not preset itself. This is the error I'm getting

```
-[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xfd5a2f0
```

I've tried everything to attempt to figure out what the released string is. Please help me figure out what the released object is when running on the device and not the simulator! Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: 
I still do not have a solution but I have confirmed the app will crash consistently on the line of code where I set a frame and the above error shows. If I comment this code out the app will pass this point but may crash at other strange spots. I can't even begin to determine where the crash is originating.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(27, 96, 265.0, 50.0);
someAcct.frame = frame;
```

I'm so confused by this since this is not a string. Any ideas?

UPDATE 2: This issue is directly related to the NSUser Defaults being synchronized. This seems pretty random but this is causing the issue. Any Help?

UPDATE 3: The problem has been solved as of a week ago. This was in fact due to a string being inaccessible. A string was passed to a method, that method then did work and passed data to another method and so on. Until finally the data was to be written to user defaults and a local plist contained within the documents folder. All of a sudden the app would crash at very strange places like the above consistently even though those places had nothing to do with a string. I was baffled and after playing with it for a very long time I decided to head over to the .h file and go through each string one at a time by making sure each were synthesized in the .m file and that self.stringName was applied throughout the .m file. After spending an hour on this I finally found the string that was to blame and the issue is now resolved. Using self.stringName allows the memory to be found and avoids these obscure and highly confusing application crashes. Thanks to everyone for all of the suggestions and tips!

Comment: You should test in instrument to find out memory leaks

Comment: You can find the affected code part my enabling NSZombie and run. Find the code part and post. So that we can help you better. :)

Comment: NSString is releases unexpectedly...u need to set property and synthesize string and use with self.

Comment: can you post some code so that you can get better answers?

Comment: Please check device crash log to find which object got over-relased.

Comment: I can test in the instruments and the same issue occurs. The app simply crashes out with no information. I'm not allocating a lot of memory. Is there some way to print out the instance number and what it actually is?

Comment: Still making no progress. I've enabled zombies but nothing point to the code in question or the double released object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is of `retain` `count`. Refer [mememory management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) and check u r not missing something.

Don't forget to turn `on` `NSZombieEnabled`.

Comment: I have enabled Zombies but this issue is so obscure I can't even begin to figure where the issue is coming from. I could post 50 pages of code. Is there any way to set something so I can determine what the instance number is?

Comment: Enabling Zombie will points you to find out the location where crashed. Try that out so that you can shortlist from the 50 pages of code. :)

Comment: I'm still struggling with this and wasting so many hours! I've enabled zombies in Xcode but it is not showing the double released object ever. It only shows this when the app crashes,
0x37314870:  bkpt   #207
0x37314872:  blx    0x37342d68                ; symbol stub for: getpid
0x37314876:  movs   r1, #9
0x37314878:  blx    0x37342e48                ; symbol stub for: kill
0x3731487c:  movs   r0, #0
0x3731487e:  b      0x37314aae                ; ___forwarding___ + 710
*** -[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa82a30
It doesn't even point to the code in question.

Answer (score 1):

To help you with tracing it down, could you try putting NSLog at the start of your didFinishLaunching() method, somewhere in the middle and at the of the didFinishLaunching().

Then also could you push a NSLog in the viewDidLoad() of the first view controller your app shows. For example, if you're using a tab bar interface, then a NSLog in the first tab's root view controller.

You can use NSLog(@"step 1"), NSLog(@"step 2"), NSLog(@"step 3") ... to organise the output so you know where the code managed to reach up to before it crash, rather than NSLog(@"I am here").

Answer (score 0):

One reason can be due to the `iOS` compatibility.Check if your device and the simulator are using the same `iOS`.Try working the simulator on the same version of OS as your device and change the `release` of the string accordingly.